# Does converting the symbol '&' to '&amp;' in XML file affect the google search?

Tags: xml

I have generated a XML sitemap, to submit to google search engine. While testing the XML file in Notepad++ and Notepad it looks perfect. But while testing with browsers like google, IE, firefox, and Edge it either shows error or not display properly. In chrome i found that the problem was due to the `&` symbol. So, I replaced the `&` symbols to `&amp;`. Now all browsers displayed properly. But, the converted URLs using `&amp;` does not works.

Does changing the `&` to `&amp;` affects the sitemap, which has to submitted google search engine?

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                                  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/about.php?course=physics&code=ptxui</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-02-23T06:29:42+01:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

The above is converted to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                                  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/about.php?course=physics&amp;code=ptxui</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-02-23T06:29:42+01:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

The second example (`&` to `&amp;`) works fine in browsers. But, the URL was invalid.

Comment: please provide a full example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this affects the google search.

It will now work, because it is now valid XML, and in XML `&amp;` is the way to represent `&` whether it's in an URI or not.

Without this you should not expect it to work.

> But, the URL was invalid.

Note that in the XML `<loc>http://www.example.com/about.php?course=physics&amp;code=ptxui</loc>` the URI given is `http://www.example.com/about.php?course=physics&code=ptxui`. You haven't turned it from a valid URI to an invalid URI, you've turned it from something that doesn't even exist because parsing the XML will fail before parsing has a chance to examine the URI into a valid URI.

Again, `&amp;` is the XML source way of representing `&`. If you want the XML to indicate `&` then you want to have `&amp;` in the source.

Comment: [Jon Hanna](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400547/jon-hanna) Shall I ignore the browser error and change it to original?

Comment: What? You've fixed it. I've just explained why you've fixed it. You do not have an invalid URI. I've just explained why you don't have an invalid URI. Why would you change it back to the original broken version?